# Rails each skipping if nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently iterating through a list of arrays, referencing data from a joined record (Students):

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @activities.compact.each do |activity| %>
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<%= activity.student.image.url(:thumb) %>)">
<% end %>
```

If for some reason a user deletes the joined record (Student), Rails throws this error:

```
NoMethodError in Activities#index
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way to tell Rails to still render the page but sub in a default value to that record if none exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! For example,

```
activity.student.try{|s| s.image.url(:thumb)} || image_path("default.png")
```

You might want to put that into a helper though, since it seems like it's starting to get complicated.

Also, I would be wary of XSS problems here if users control any part of the attachment URL (e.g. if you are using the filename of their uploaded file). I'm not sure whether erb does the right thing when outputting to an attribute. Maybe it does---I'm just not sure.

Comment: Just to follow up, I did some testing, and it looks like ERB does the right thing after all, so my XSS worry was unnecessary.

Comment: For example `<% ['">woops</div><div style="'].each do |x| %>
  <div style="<%= x %>"><%= x %></div>
<% end %>
` is okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you use carrierwave gem for uploads, there'a built-in solution for default images https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<% @activities.compact.each do |activity| %>
    <% if activity.student.present? %>
    <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<%= activity.student.image.url(:thumb) %>)">
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```